# TypeScript - function to map union type to another union type based on discriminator

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have 2 discriminated union types that use the same discriminator field + values. I'm trying to write a function that can map 1 to the other based on the discriminator.

e.g.

**Input type:**

```
type InA = {
    type: 'a',
    data: string
};

type InB = {
    type: 'b',
    data: number
};

type In = InA | InB;
```

**Output type:**

```
type OutA = {
    type: 'a',
    data: Object
};

type OutB = {
    type: 'b',
    data: Array<number>
};

type Out = OutA | OutB;
```

**Mapping function**

```
// This is the function I'd like to have a better type signature
// for inferring output type based on input type
function map<In, Out>(
    in: In
): Out {
   // do something
}
```

**Usage**

```
// I want the compiler to infer that this is OutB based on the InB
let result = map({ type: 'b', value: 999 });
```

Is there a way to write the function signature for **map** such that this will work?

**UPDATED AFTER ANSWERED**
I was able to use a modified version of @titian-cernicova-dragomir answer. Here's the general idea + some additional context as to how I'm using it:

```
/** Http Request types **/

type RequestA = {
    type: 'names',
    url: '/names'
};

type RequestB = {
    type: 'numbers',
    url: '/numbers'
};

type Request = RequestA | RequestB;

/** Response types **/

type ResponseA = {
    type: 'names',
    data: Array<string>
};

type ResponseB = {
    type: 'numbers',
    data: Array<number>
};

type Response = ResponseA | ResponseB;

/** Helper from accepted answer */
type GetOut<T, A> = T extends { type: A } ? T : never;

/** Generic function for fetching data */
export function fetchData<
    Req extends Request,
    Res extends GetOut<Response, Req['type']>
    >(request: Req): Promise<Res> {
    return fetch(request.url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            return <Res>{
                type: request.type,
                data
            }
        });
}

// compiler knows that this is of type Promise<ResponseA> based on
// type discriminiator
let names = fetchData({
    type: 'names',
    url: '/names'
});

// compiler knows that this is of type Promise<ResponseB> based on
// type discriminiator
let numbers = fetchData({
    type: 'numbers',
    url: '/numbers'
});
```

Comment: I'm curious whether anyone has a better solution to this, but I suspect because you can't actually read the generically passed type at runtime under any circumstances, what you're trying to do would be impossible. My next go-to would be to include a constructor function rather than a string representation of the type you were trying to infer. Where type: typeof ParentClass. That would allow you to put a "name" parameter in each subclass and retrieve it later, and still stay relatively strongly typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional types to do this. First we use a conditional type to extract the actual string literal type that is passed as an argument (we will call it `A`). Then using `A` we will filter `Out` to get the type from the unon that extends `{ type: A }`.

```
type GetOut<T, A> = T extends { type : A} ? T: never; 
function map2<TIn extends In>(inParam: TIn) : TIn extends { type: infer A } ? GetOut<Out, A> : never {
    return null as any;
}

let resultA = map2({ type: 'a', data: '999' }); // result is OutA
let resultB = map2({ type: 'b', data: 999 }); // result is OutB
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20InA%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%09data%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20InB%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%09data%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20In%20%3D%20InA%20%7C%20InB%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OutA%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%09data%3A%20Object%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OutB%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%09data%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Out%20%3D%20OutA%20%7C%20OutB%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20GetOut%3CT%2C%20A%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%20%3A%20A%7D%20%3F%20T%3A%20never%3B%20%0D%0Afunction%20map2%3CTIn%20extends%20In%3E(inParam%3A%20TIn)%20%3A%20TIn%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20infer%20A%20%7D%20%3F%20GetOut%3COut%2C%20A%3E%20%3A%20never%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20resultA%20%3D%20map2(%7B%20type%3A%20'a'%2C%20data%3A%20'999'%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20result%20is%20OutA%0D%0Alet%20resultB%20%3D%20map2(%7B%20type%3A%20'b'%2C%20data%3A%20999%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20result%20is%20OutB)

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not mention this as 2.8 is the current version. Conditional type were introduced in 2.8

Comment: @bhoo-day An alternative for pre 2.8 is to use multiple overloads